# When is the maximal ideal of a zero-dimensional local non-noetherian commutative ring nilpotent?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a non-Noetherian local commutative ring with identity such that it is of Krull-dimension zero. I am wondering if there are conditions which will force the maximal ideal to be nilpotent.

Comment: What do you mean by "the only prime ideal"? There is no reason why there is only one prime ideal.

Comment: Martin is absolutely right: if $R$ has only one prime ideal, it is of dimension zero! (And then that prime ideal indeed consists of nilpotent elements but needn't be nilpotent)

Comment: Since your ring is local, did you perhaps mean to type "the only $maximal$ ideal"?  I think this would make your question interesting.

Comment: I must apologize. I was a bit confused by the definition of the dimension in a ring. Yes, it should be 0-dimensional ring. So we have a 0-dimensional local ring. Then the maximum ideal's elements are nilpotent. I was wondering if there are conditions that forces the ideal itself to be nilpotent. Thank you all for correcting me.

Comment: Now it makes sense; in fact a ring is local and $0$-dimensional iff it has a unique prime ideal. I have corrected the question. I hope it's ok, otherwise use the edit function.

Comment: Here is a class of examples: Let $R$ be a (non-noetheran) ring, $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal and consider $R/\mathfrak{m}^n$

Comment: Why Martin Brandenburg's correction was changed ? Please correct only if it is needed. Martin's correction was just right. Sorry for this non-mathematical comments.

Answer (score 7):

This is a broad question...

A necessary condition for the maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ to be nilpotent is $R$ is separated for the $\mathfrak m$-adic topology: 
$$ \cap_{n\ge 1} \mathfrak m^n=0.$$ 
Now suppose moreover that $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ is finite dimensional over $R/\mathfrak m$, then $\mathfrak m$ is nilpotent.

Proof: let $I\subseteq \mathfrak m$ be a finitely generated ideal which generates $\mathfrak m$ modulo $\mathfrak m^2$. Let $N>0$ be such that $I^N=0$ ($N$ exists because $I$ is finitely generated). For any $n>0$, we have $\mathfrak m=I+ \mathfrak m^n$ and 
$$\mathfrak m^{N}\subseteq I^N+\mathfrak m^n=\mathfrak m^n.$$ 
Therefore $\mathfrak m^{N}\subseteq \cap_n \mathfrak m^n=0$.

Of course in general, $ \mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ is not finite dimensional. I don't know whether the above condition is reasonable for you.

Comment: Can you give a nontrivial example where $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ is finite, but $\mathfrak{m}$ is not?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I don't know what do you call nontrivial. In general we can have $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2=0$ and  $\mathfrak m$ not of finite type (e.g. continuous functions in a neighborhood of $0\in\mathbb R$), but I don't have such an example in dimension $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much QiL'8.

Comment: @Martin: Dear Martin, Here is one example where $R$ is of dimension zero, $\mathfrak m = \mathfrak m^2$, but $\mathfrak m$ is not finitely generated: $R = k[X,X^{1/2},X^{1/3},...]/(X)$.  Once you see this example, you can make many others.  Regards,

Comment: Thank you. By nontrivial I meant that $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ has a given dimension $n>0$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: take any example $R$ with $\mathfrak m=\mathfrak m^2$ and tensor over $k$ with $k[Y_1, \dots, Y_n]/(Y_i^{2})_i$.